# Use unicode-math character with pdfLaTex compiler

Tags: pdftex, xetex, luatex, unicode, unicode-math

I want to use the `\squareulblack` symbol (or others) from the `unicode-math` package, but I have to keep compiling with pdfLaTex (since the document has evolved always using this compiler and it would be a paint to now make it work with XeLaTex).

How can I do this?

Comment: open with `texdoc symbols` the large symbol list and look if some package provide your symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol is provided by `stix2`, but you probably don't want to change your fonts to the Times based STIX2 font.

In `stix2.sty` we find

```
\stix@MathSymbol{\squareulblack}{\mathord}{arrows3}{"88}
\stix@MathSymbol{\squarelrblack}{\mathord}{arrows3}{"89}
```

so we know that we need to find the definition of the math symbol font `arrows3`

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows3}{LS2}{stix2tt}{m}{n}
```

so we need to declare the `LS2` encoding

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}
```

The `\noaccents@` declaration is irrelevant for our purposes. Now we can import the symbols. However, the first attempt does not really mix with `\square`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}

\newcommand{\stixtwottsymbol}[1]{%
  \text{\usefont{LS2}{stix2tt}{m}{n}\symbol{#1}}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\squareulblack}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathrel or \mathbin
    \stixtwottsymbol{"88}%
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\squarelrblack}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathrel or \mathbin
    \stixtwottsymbol{"89}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\vrule depth 0.1pt height 0.1pt width 3pt $\squareulblack \square \squarelrblack$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The symbols are larger and don't sit on the baseline. Let's fix the issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}

\newcommand{\stixtwottsymbol}[1]{%
  \text{%
    \settoheight{\dimen0}{$\square$}%
    \resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{%
      \raisebox{\depth}{\usefont{LS2}{stix2tt}{m}{n}\symbol{#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\squareulblack}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathrel or \mathbin
    \stixtwottsymbol{"88}%
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\squarelrblack}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathrel or \mathbin
    \stixtwottsymbol{"89}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\vrule depth 0.1pt height 0.1pt width 3pt $\squareulblack \square \squarelrblack$

$\scriptstyle \squareulblack \square \squarelrblack$

$\scriptscriptstyle \squareulblack \square \squarelrblack$

\end{document}
```

The result is much better, isn't it?

[image]

Also the previous version scales well in the other math styles.

Comment: disaster! You got the tick. See comments under my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Working crystal ball…

Answer (score 2):

The `stix2` package has more or less the full set of `unicode-math` names for pdflatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}

$\squareulblack$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am indeed able to use the symbol now. However, the font of the whole document is also automatically changed, which I don't want. When I set the notext and nomath option of the package, to avoid that, the symbol is not available anymore. How can I only import this specific symbol (or any other) from the stix2 package?

Comment: @stollenm much as it pains me to suggest it, see egreg's answer

Comment: Oupps, somehow this answer didn't show up until now. I should have refreshed the browser. Thanks.